# Python: PyautoGui Mouse Click Not working neither locateScreen based on screenshot

Tags: python, pyautogui

Below code stops after printing hello and nothing happens.
Tried different option as  pyautogui.leftClick(993, 578) but no luck.
In below code if I don't use subprocess but keep zoom GUI open then click is working fine.

```
import subprocess
import pyautogui
import time
import os
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

print("hello")
subprocess.call("C:\\Users\xyz\\AppData\\Roaming\\Zoom\\bin\\Zoom.exe")
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.moveTo(993, 578, 0)
pyautogui.leftClick()
print(1)
```

Comment: Why do you have two `pyautogui.moveTo()` statements within each other?

Comment: the statement to click is pyautogui.click()

Comment: @Codeman I corrected but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

The simple problem i see with your code is this line:

```
subprocess.call("C:\\Users\xyz\\AppData\\Roaming\\Zoom\\bin\\Zoom.exe")
```

You've missed a `\` before the `xyz`.

The following works perfectly for me on Python 3.6+:

```
import pyautogui
import time
import os

print("begun")
os.system(r"C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\Zoom\bin\Zoom.exe")
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.moveTo(pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('my image'))
pyautogui.click()
print("dun")
```

If this doesn't work, try the `pydirectinput` module too, it's the updated version of `pyautogui` with much the same functions.